# how to change creative font in web design

Tags: website-design, css, html, newsletter

I have created a newsletter in html & inline css.

When I change my font, it will change to the new font on my system. But when I open another system, the font has not changed.

How can I make sure it changes on all systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System fonts work the same in email clients as they do on the web. But a font will only display if it is installed on that system.

Using an example:

```
<td style="Arial, Georgia, 'Comic Sans';">Your Text here</td>
```

- If a system has Arial installed, it displays that.
- Else if it has Georgia installed, it displays that.
- Else if it has Comic Sans installed (God No!), it displays that.

And so on.

So if you check different systems and they display different fonts, it might be because they don't have the same fonts installed locally.

Comment: the word you're looking for is _web-safe fonts_